# Why SELECT ... FOR SHARE is not blocked by another transaction's UPDATE？

Tags: mysql, database, transactions, mariadb

Schema:

```
CREATE TABLE `table0` (
  `pkId` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `pkAttr0` int NOT NULL,
  `coAttr0_0` int DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`pkAttr0`),
  KEY `table0index_pk` (`pkAttr0`),
  KEY `table0index_commAttr0` (`coAttr0_0`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;

insert into table0 values(1,1,1);
```

Then execute:

```
session1 > begin;
session1 > update table0 set coAttr0_0=2;
session2 > begin;
session2 > select pkAttr0 from table0 for share; -- is not blocked
session2 > select * from table0 for share; -- blocked
```

`session1 > update table0 set coAttr0_0=2;` has locked the row, why is `session2 > select pkAttr0 from table0 for share;` still able to execute?

Comment: For completeness please add the result of show create table table0 including the storage engine..

Answer (score 0):

Not an expert on locks, but I think it depends on the fact that you're `select`-ing an attribute that is not involved in the `update` operation, while `select *` will require the lock to be released first, as `coAttr0_0` is (possibly) being updated.

Answer (score 0):

check the autocommit mode:

Manual:

If autocommit is set to 1 (the default), the LOCK IN SHARE MODE and FOR UPDATE clauses **have no effect**.

https://mariadb.com/kb/en/lock-in-share-mode/

Comment: I'm curious: shouldn't that have avoided lock in **all** selects?

Comment: I think OP expects that a begin..update with implicit lock in one session will be honoured by a begin in another session. Personally I would use a start transaction in preference to a begin

Comment: I start a transaction with `begin` command, maybe it should't be affected by `autocommit=1`?

Answer (score 0):

This answer is based on my test. I find that The `SELECT for share` is not blocked if all the columns (excluding the ones which are updated, in this case, column coAttr0_0) in the select list are included in a single index, regardless of it being unique or not. 
Depending on whether the update actually changes value, if it does, the columns in the index must be precise (e.g there is only one column in the select clause, then there must be a single-column index for that column. A composite index covering that column would not count, even if the column is the leftmost one in the index). If no actual change is being made, the columns in the index only need to be inclusive (e.g there are two columns in the select clause, then the index can be a 5-column index which has the two columns in it).

This is the index using your table structure.

```
+--------+------------+-----------------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+---------+------------+
| Table  | Non_unique | Key_name              | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment | Visible | Expression |
+--------+------------+-----------------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+---------+------------+
| table0 |          0 | PRIMARY               |            1 | pkAttr0     | A         |           1 |     NULL |   NULL |      | BTREE      |         |               | YES     | NULL       |
| table0 |          1 | table0index_pk        |            1 | pkAttr0     | A         |           1 |     NULL |   NULL |      | BTREE      |         |               | YES     | NULL       |
| table0 |          1 | table0index_commAttr0 |            1 | coAttr0_0   | A         |           1 |     NULL |   NULL | YES  | BTREE      |         |               | YES     | NULL       |
+--------+------------+-----------------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+---------+------------+
```

As we can see, column `pkId` is not indexed.Let's begin the test:

```
session1 > begin;
session1 > update table0 set coAttr0_0=2;
session2 > begin;
session2 > select pkAttr0 from table0 for share; -- is not blocked
session2 > select * from table0 for share; -- blocked
session2 > select pkId from table0 for share; -- blocked
session2 > select coAttr0_0 from table0 for share; -- blocked
```

As denoted above, neither column `pkId` (not indexed) nor `coAttr0_0` (pending update) is successful. 
Now we drop the PK attribute and the index for pkAttr0 , while add an index for pkId. Then test again. Note: `Commit` should be submitted before we make the structure changes.

```
session1 > commit;
session2 > commit;

alter table table0 drop primary key;
drop index table0index_pk on table0;
create index idx_pkid on table0(pkId);

 show index in table0;
+--------+------------+-----------------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+---------+------------+
| Table  | Non_unique | Key_name              | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment | Visible | Expression |
+--------+------------+-----------------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+---------+------------+
| table0 |          1 | table0index_commAttr0 |            1 | coAttr0_0   | A         |           1 |     NULL |   NULL | YES  | BTREE      |         |               | YES     | NULL       |
| table0 |          1 | idx_pkid              |            1 | pkId        | A         |           0 |     NULL |   NULL | YES  | BTREE      |         |               | YES     | NULL       |
+--------+------------+-----------------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+---------+------------+
```

Now we only have index for `pkId` and `coAttr0_0`. Let's continue the test:

```
session1 > begin;
session1 > update table0 set coAttr0_0=20; -- value to be changed from 2 to 20
session2 > begin;
session2 > select pkAttr0 from table0 for share; -- blocked
session2 > select * from table0 for share; -- blocked
session2 > select pkId from table0 for share; -- is not blocked
session2 > select coAttr0_0 from table0 for share; -- blocked

session1 > commit;
session2 > commit;
```

However, what if we run an update statement that does not actually change values. For example, during the last step we changed `coAttr0_0` from 2 to 20. What if we make the same update statement which actually doesn't change anything?

```
session1 > begin;
session1 > update table0 set coAttr0_0=20; -- the new value is the same as the old one so no change is made
session2 > begin;
session2 > select pkAttr0 from table0 for share; -- blocked
session2 > select * from table0 for share; -- blocked
session2 > select pkId from table0 for share; -- is not blocked
session2 > select coAttr0_0 from table0 for share; -- is not blocked !!

session1 > commit;
session2 > commit;
```

This time, the `select coAttr0_0 from table0 for share;` statement is not blocked. 
Next, we shall create a key for `pkAttr0` and delve deeper.

```
create index idx_pkattr0 on table0(pkAttr0);
show index in table0;

+--------+------------+-----------------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+---------+------------+
| Table  | Non_unique | Key_name              | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment | Visible | Expression |
+--------+------------+-----------------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+---------+------------+
| table0 |          1 | table0index_commAttr0 |            1 | coAttr0_0   | A         |           0 |     NULL |   NULL | YES  | BTREE      |         |               | YES     | NULL       |
| table0 |          1 | idx_pkid              |            1 | pkId        | A         |           0 |     NULL |   NULL | YES  | BTREE      |         |               | YES     | NULL       |
| table0 |          1 | idx_pkattr0           |            1 | pkAttr0     | A         |           0 |     NULL |   NULL |      | BTREE      |         |               | YES     | NULL       |
+--------+------------+-----------------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+---------+------------+

session1 > begin;
session1 > update table0 set coAttr0_0=200; -- value from 20 to 200
session2 > begin;
session2 > select pkAttr0 from table0 for share; -- is not blocked
session2 > select * from table0 for share; -- blocked
session2 > select pkId from table0 for share; -- is not blocked
session2 > select coAttr0_0 from table0 for share; -- blocked 

-- Pay attention to this one
session2 > select pkId,pkAttr0 from table0 for share; -- blocked

session1 > commit;
session2 > commit;
```

As emphasized above, when the select clause has both pkId and pkAttr0, the statement is blocked, even if both columns are individually indexed. Now let's create a composite index to cover both columns.

```
create index idx_both on table0( pkAttr0,pkId);

 show index in table0;
+--------+------------+-----------------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+---------+------------+
| Table  | Non_unique | Key_name              | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment | Visible | Expression |
+--------+------------+-----------------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+---------+------------+
| table0 |          1 | table0index_commAttr0 |            1 | coAttr0_0   | A         |           0 |     NULL |   NULL | YES  | BTREE      |         |               | YES     | NULL       |
| table0 |          1 | idx_pkid              |            1 | pkId        | A         |           0 |     NULL |   NULL | YES  | BTREE      |         |               | YES     | NULL       |
| table0 |          1 | idx_pkattr0           |            1 | pkAttr0     | A         |           0 |     NULL |   NULL |      | BTREE      |         |               | YES     | NULL       |
| table0 |          1 | idx_both              |            1 | pkAttr0     | A         |           0 |     NULL |   NULL |      | BTREE      |         |               | YES     | NULL       |
| table0 |          1 | idx_both              |            2 | pkId        | A         |           0 |     NULL |   NULL | YES  | BTREE      |         |               | YES     | NULL       |
+--------+------------+-----------------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+---------+------------+

session1 > begin;
session1 > update table0 set coAttr0_0=2000; -- value from 200 to 2000
session2 > begin;
session2 > select pkAttr0 from table0 for share; -- is not blocked
session2 > select * from table0 for share; -- blocked
session2 > select pkId from table0 for share; -- is not blocked
session2 > select coAttr0_0 from table0 for share; -- blocked 

-- see what happens this time:
session2 > select pkId,pkAttr0 from table0 for share; -- is not blocked !!

session1 > commit;
session2 > commit;
```

As we can see , with the composite index, the select clause that has both columns is not blocked.
Nonetheless, what if we remove the individual indexes for pkId,pkAttr0? Will this change the output?

```
drop index idx_pkid on table0;
drop index idx_pkattr0 on table0;

show index in table0;
+--------+------------+-----------------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+---------+------------+
| Table  | Non_unique | Key_name              | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment | Visible | Expression |
+--------+------------+-----------------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+---------+------------+
| table0 |          1 | table0index_commAttr0 |            1 | coAttr0_0   | A         |           0 |     NULL |   NULL | YES  | BTREE      |         |               | YES     | NULL       |
| table0 |          1 | idx_both              |            1 | pkAttr0     | A         |           0 |     NULL |   NULL |      | BTREE      |         |               | YES     | NULL       |
| table0 |          1 | idx_both              |            2 | pkId        | A         |           0 |     NULL |   NULL | YES  | BTREE      |         |               | YES     | NULL       |
+--------+------------+-----------------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+---------+------------+

session1 > begin;
session1 > update table0 set coAttr0_0=2000; -- value does not change this time
session2 > begin;
session2 > select pkAttr0 from table0 for share; -- is not blocked
session2 > select * from table0 for share; -- blocked

-- BOOKMARK this one
session2 > select pkId from table0 for share; -- is not blocked


session2 > select coAttr0_0 from table0 for share; -- is not blocked 
session2 > select pkId,pkAttr0 from table0 for share; -- is not blocked 

session1 > commit;
session2 > commit;
```

As demonstrated above, the output remains the same as the previous test after we removed the individual indexes for column `pkId` and `pkAttr0` (except this time the one selecting `coAttr0_0` is not blocked due to no actual change happening).
Now let's move our focus on the bookmarked query. i.e `select pkId from table0 for share;`. Interestingly, unlike the one selecting `pkAttr0` , this one with `pkId` is not executed using the index due to the leftmost prefix rule for index utilisation, as now only the composite index remains and the `pkAttr0` is the first one in index sequence. Therefore, as long as the index includes the column, the index sequence does not matter in aspect of blocking.
Finally, let's remove the current composite index and create a new one including all columns.

```
drop index idx_both on table0;
create index idx_all on table0(coAttr0_0,pkId,pkAttr0);

show index in table0;
+--------+------------+-----------------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+---------+------------+
| Table  | Non_unique | Key_name              | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment | Visible | Expression |
+--------+------------+-----------------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+---------+------------+
| table0 |          1 | table0index_commAttr0 |            1 | coAttr0_0   | A         |           0 |     NULL |   NULL | YES  | BTREE      |         |               | YES     | NULL       |
| table0 |          1 | idx_all               |            1 | coAttr0_0   | A         |           0 |     NULL |   NULL | YES  | BTREE      |         |               | YES     | NULL       |
| table0 |          1 | idx_all               |            2 | pkId        | A         |           0 |     NULL |   NULL | YES  | BTREE      |         |               | YES     | NULL       |
| table0 |          1 | idx_all               |            3 | pkAttr0     | A         |           0 |     NULL |   NULL |      | BTREE      |         |               | YES     | NULL       |
+--------+------------+-----------------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+---------+------------+

session1 > begin;
session1 > update table0 set coAttr0_0=2000; -- value still does not change 
session2 > begin;
session2 > select pkAttr0 from table0 for share; -- is not blocked
session2 > select * from table0 for share; -- is not blocked !!

session2 > select pkId from table0 for share; -- is not blocked
session2 > select coAttr0_0 from table0 for share; -- is not blocked 
session2 > select pkId,pkAttr0 from table0 for share; -- is not blocked 

session1 > commit;
session2 > commit;
```

Finally, the query `select * from table0 for share;` is not blocked this time. Of course, had the UPDATE statement actually changed values , the result would have been the same except the those having `coAttr0_0` in the select list. That is what one might normally think. WRONG !!

```
session1 > begin;
session1 > update table0 set coAttr0_0=32167; -- value changed from 2000 
session2 > begin;
session2 > select pkAttr0 from table0 for share; -- blocked !!
session2 > select * from table0 for share; -- blocked 

session2 > select pkId from table0 for share; -- blocked !!
session2 > select coAttr0_0 from table0 for share; -- blocked 
session2 > select pkId,pkAttr0 from table0 for share; -- blocked !!
 

session1 > commit;
session2 > commit;
```

As `coAttr0_0` actually had its value changed, no column in the composite index which covers every column is permitted in the `select for share` statement. How about we add an individual index for a column ? This time we create one for `pkAttr0`. Also, column `coAttr0_0` shall be changed backed to 2000.

```
create index idx_pkAttr0 on table0(pkAttr0);

show index in table0;
+--------+------------+-----------------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+---------+------------+
| Table  | Non_unique | Key_name              | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment | Visible | Expression |
+--------+------------+-----------------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+---------+------------+
| table0 |          1 | table0index_commAttr0 |            1 | coAttr0_0   | A         |           0 |     NULL |   NULL | YES  | BTREE      |         |               | YES     | NULL       |
| table0 |          1 | idx_all               |            1 | coAttr0_0   | A         |           0 |     NULL |   NULL | YES  | BTREE      |         |               | YES     | NULL       |
| table0 |          1 | idx_all               |            2 | pkId        | A         |           0 |     NULL |   NULL | YES  | BTREE      |         |               | YES     | NULL       |
| table0 |          1 | idx_all               |            3 | pkAttr0     | A         |           0 |     NULL |   NULL |      | BTREE      |         |               | YES     | NULL       |
| table0 |          1 | idx_pkAttr0           |            1 | pkAttr0     | A         |           1 |     NULL |   NULL |      | BTREE      |         |               | YES     | NULL       |
+--------+------------+-----------------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+---------+------------+

session1 > begin;
session1 > update table0 set coAttr0_0=2000; -- value changed from 32167 back to 2000 
session2 > begin;
session2 > select pkAttr0 from table0 for share; -- is not blocked 
session2 > select * from table0 for share; -- blocked 

session2 > select pkId from table0 for share; -- blocked 
session2 > select coAttr0_0 from table0 for share; -- blocked 
session2 > select pkId,pkAttr0 from table0 for share; -- blocked 
 

session1 > commit;
session2 > commit;
```

After creating an individual index for `pkAttr0`, this time `select pkAttr0 from table0 for share;` is not blocked when `coAttr0_0` has its value changed. And without an individual index for column `pkId`, `select pkId from table0 for share;` is blocked. 
Does the index sequence really not matter when actually changes is happening? Let's find out by dropping the composite index and the indivial index( for `pkAttr0` ), then create a brand new composite index covering all columns but in different sequence.

```
drop index idx_all on table0;
drop index idx_pkAttr0 on table0;

create index idx_all_new on table0 (pkId,pkAttr0,coAttr0_0);

show index in table0;
+--------+------------+-----------------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+---------+------------+
| Table  | Non_unique | Key_name              | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment | Visible | Expression |
+--------+------------+-----------------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+---------+------------+
| table0 |          1 | table0index_commAttr0 |            1 | coAttr0_0   | A         |           0 |     NULL |   NULL | YES  | BTREE      |         |               | YES     | NULL       |
| table0 |          1 | idx_all_new           |            1 | pkId        | A         |           1 |     NULL |   NULL | YES  | BTREE      |         |               | YES     | NULL       |
| table0 |          1 | idx_all_new           |            2 | pkAttr0     | A         |           1 |     NULL |   NULL |      | BTREE      |         |               | YES     | NULL       |
| table0 |          1 | idx_all_new           |            3 | coAttr0_0   | A         |           1 |     NULL |   NULL | YES  | BTREE      |         |               | YES     | NULL       |
+--------+------------+-----------------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+---------+------------+

session1 > begin;
session1 > update table0 set coAttr0_0=9999; -- value changed from 2000 to 9999
session2 > begin;
session2 > select pkAttr0 from table0 for share; -- blocked 
session2 > select * from table0 for share; -- blocked 

session2 > select pkId from table0 for share; -- blocked 
session2 > select coAttr0_0 from table0 for share; -- blocked 
session2 > select pkId,pkAttr0 from table0 for share; -- blocked 

session1 > commit;
session2 > commit;
```

As shown above, even we put `pkId` first in the composite index, the `select pkId from table0 for share;` is still blocked when `coAttr0_0` changed. OK. Let's create an individual index for `pkId`.

```
create index idx_pkid on table0(pkId);

show index in table0;
+--------+------------+-----------------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+---------+------------+
| Table  | Non_unique | Key_name              | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment | Visible | Expression |
+--------+------------+-----------------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+---------+------------+
| table0 |          1 | table0index_commAttr0 |            1 | coAttr0_0   | A         |           0 |     NULL |   NULL | YES  | BTREE      |         |               | YES     | NULL       |
| table0 |          1 | idx_all_new           |            1 | pkId        | A         |           1 |     NULL |   NULL | YES  | BTREE      |         |               | YES     | NULL       |
| table0 |          1 | idx_all_new           |            2 | pkAttr0     | A         |           1 |     NULL |   NULL |      | BTREE      |         |               | YES     | NULL       |
| table0 |          1 | idx_all_new           |            3 | coAttr0_0   | A         |           1 |     NULL |   NULL | YES  | BTREE      |         |               | YES     | NULL       |
| table0 |          1 | idx_pkid              |            1 | pkId        | A         |           0 |     NULL |   NULL | YES  | BTREE      |         |               | YES     | NULL       |
+--------+------------+-----------------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+---------+------------+

session1 > begin;
session1 > update table0 set coAttr0_0=7777; -- value changed from 9999 to 7777
session2 > begin;
session2 > select pkAttr0 from table0 for share; -- blocked 
session2 > select * from table0 for share; -- blocked 

session2 > select pkId from table0 for share; -- no longer blocked !! 
session2 > select coAttr0_0 from table0 for share; -- blocked 
session2 > select pkId,pkAttr0 from table0 for share; -- blocked 


session1 > commit;
session2 > commit;
```

With the individual index for `pkId` , the `select pkId from table0 for share;` is not blocked anymore when coAttr0_0 changes.
Now let's make a final test.(for real this time) In the finale, all indexes remain the same as last time, but `coAttr0_0` does not change this time.

```
session1 > begin;
session1 > update table0 set coAttr0_0=7777; -- value does not change
session2 > begin;
session2 > select pkAttr0 from table0 for share; -- is not blocked 
session2 > select * from table0 for share; -- is not blocked 

session2 > select pkId from table0 for share; -- is not blocked even without an individual index for itself 
session2 > select coAttr0_0 from table0 for share; -- is not blocked 
session2 > select pkId,pkAttr0 from table0 for share; -- is not blocked 


session1 > commit;
session2 > commit;
```

**Conclusion** 
When a column update does not change value, the `select for share` statement is not blocked as long as all the columns in the select list are included in a single index, which can be an index having more columns than the ones in the select clause.
But when update does change value for a column, the `select for share` statement is not blocked only if a precise match is possible between the columns in the select list and the columns in the index. e.g, a single column index for `pkId` must exist for the query `select pkId from table0 for share;` to run successfully. A composite index including `pkId` would not work in this case.  That's to say, no more, no less. 
However, in both cases, the column sequence in a composite index is trivial when it comes to blocking.